# Heuristic algorithm for finding minimal value from function

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to apply a heuristic algorithm for finding a minimum or maximum from a function.

I understood what heuristic means, but where can I find an algorithm for applying it on [Rosenbrock function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function), for example.

(C++,JAVA,C# or even pseudocode could be very helpful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest, and most obvious, solution would be to use the **Random walk** algorithm. It works by starting with a random point within the search space and then visiting it's random neighbor.

A similar, but more reasonable, algorithm is the **Hill climbing**. Again, you start at a random point but this time you chose the best neighbor.

Another, technically, heuristic algorithm is **Random sampling**, which just means picking any point from the search space and remembering the best one you found.

An improvement over Random sampling is the **Simulated annealing** algorithm. It's a kind of a fusion of Random sampling and Hill climbing: you start with picking random points in the search space but as the time goes on you tend to stick with the higher quality ones.

You can find more information and pseudo code samples of all of the above on Wikipedia.

A whole different class of solutions are the **Genetic algorithms**. You can start learning about them by reading http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/index.php. Unfortunately it does not seem to have any code samples.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article that you reference mentions [adaptive coordinate descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_coordinate_descent), which is a state-of-the-art evolutionary algorithm, as a technique for minimizing the Rosenbrock function. Googling that finds several papers with pseudocode and algorithms including [this one](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/58/75/34/PDF/AdaptiveCoordinateDescent.pdf). The paper even includes a reference to [actual code in Matlab](https://sites.google.com/site/acdgecco/).

You could also use Expectation–maximization with random restart although that's probably significantly less efficient than adaptive coordinate descent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [partial derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) of the function to find its extrema. You start from a random point on the plane and use these derivatives (calculated numerically) to find a direction to move to a next point. Repeat this process until you find a minimum (justified by second derivatives).

By the way, the function you are talking about is a known difficult case for such iterative search, so you'll need to experiment with step size and other parameters of your algorithm.